# Restrict selection of multiple cells inside table in html, how to use user-select property for a table

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I have a small requirement, where I'm looking for disabling the selection of table, but not **td** or **th**.
I have tried approaches where, I have used user-select attribute for disabling it, but it is disabling the whole table.
Can you please help me in this.
Also, how to use the user-select attribute for a class where class name is like "com.binay.userSelectProperty.HelloWorld" where HelloWolrd.java is my class.

Please find the code below:

```css
.text-selection-none{
user-select: none; /* supported by Chrome and Opera */
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
-khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" class="text-selection-none">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Above class="**text-selection-none**" I have tried even putting inside , which makes the full  as non-selectable.
But what I am looking for is, disabling only the table selection, not the text selection.
If not possible, then atleast let me know how to apply the property to my real-time class "com.binay.userSelectProperty.HelloWorld".

Comment: Have you tried replacing `none` with `text`?

Answer (score -1):

Add the **text-selection-none** class to the **tr**s or the **th**s.